# Проблема с кодировкой украинского текста

Tags: c#

Есть метод, который парсит текстовый файл.

```
public void Parse(string FilePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FilePath, Encoding.Default))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Parsed_Lines.Add(line);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Parsed_Lines[1]);
    }
```

В текстовом файле содержится текст на украинском языке. Программа отрабатывает, но при выводе на консоль получаем результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это пофиксить и есть ли какая-то универсальная кодировка, что-ли, что-бы любой текст независимо от языка отображался читабельно.

Comment: какая кодировка у вашего текстового файла?

Comment: CHARSET "WindowsCyrillic"

Comment: попробуйте UTF-8

Comment: пробовал - эффект тот же, хотя метанит говорит что должно с кирриллицей работать на утф-8 https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.5.php

Comment: Первое правило: **никогда** не используйте `Encoding.Default`. Это та кодировка, которая установлена в данный момент на компьютере, где запускается этот код. То есть на разных компьютерах это будут _разные_ кодировки. | Тогда какую использовать? Ту же самую, в которой был записан этот файл.